# Is there a fix for InheritanceManager breaking static type checking?

Tags: mypy, django-model-utils

I have added django-model-utils to an existing (large) project, and the build is now failing, as part of the build includes static type checking with mypy.

It complains that models that I have added `objects = InheritanceManager()` to, don't have attributes for reverse ForeignKeys, if the reverse FK is accessed in a method on that model.  For example, take the following:

```
class Student(Model):
    school = ForeignKey(School, related_name='students')

class School(Model):
    objects = InheritanceManager()  # IRL School is a subclass of some other model
    def something(self):
        return self.students.filter(...)
```

Then running mypy on it, will return:

```
error: "School" has no attribute "students"
```

And even if I remove the related_name, and use self.student_set (i.e. the default django relation), it will still produce the same type of error.  Only removing the InheritanceManager fixes the static type checking.  Of course, I'm using it for a reason as I need to `select_subclasses` elsewhere in the code.

Has anyone come across this, or have a fix?

Answer (score 0):

`django-stubs` uses plugin to add all managers. This plugin is triggered only if added manager is a "subclass" (not just real subclass, but also recognizable by `mypy` as such) of `models.Manager`.

`django-model-utils` is untyped, so `InheritanceManager` is in fact `Any` for `mypy`, and plugin does not see it. To solve exactly this issue I was adding `py.typed` marker to `django-model-utils` as a CI stage after package installation. You can also use a fork with `py.typed` or create a stub package for `django-model-utils`. This can result in other issues and doesn't give good type checking (all unannotated methods have `Any` as implicit arguments and return type), but is better than nothing. For my needs the marker was sufficient.

`py.typed` marker is an empty file located in package root (`venv/lib/.../django_model_utils/py.typed`) - it tells `mypy` that package does not need separate stubs and contains all necessary types.

Comment: But I'm not getting errors about stubs or any problems directly with model utils as a package (like you would get if you don't add django-stubs to a django project), it's literally just these reverse foreign keys that are the issue.  Would a py.typed marker help with that somehow?

Comment: Yes, it would. You don't have errors from this packages, most probably because you have `ignore_missing_imports=True` or `follow_imports=skip` `mypy` config, so everything imported from `django_model_utils` is `Any` and does not have `models.Manager` as base. I contributed to `django-stubs` plugin system, so I'm 100% sure that `objects = Something()` adds reverse managers iff `Something <: models.Manager`.

Comment: @DavidDownes have you found a reasonable solution to this problem? We're facing the exact same issue.

Comment: @Barnercart to resolve just the issue in the question my answer is sufficient - just checked on a demo project setup. `touch venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/model_utils/py.typed` creates a marker for `mypy`, you can run this in CI pipeline. Also you can fork `django-model-utils` and add py.typed. If you need more support than just understanding their manages as `models.Manager` suclasses, you may want to run `stubgen` and create a stub package (and release it! The community will like this), read [here](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stubgen.html).

Comment: @SUTerliakov thanks but maybe it is reasonable to just wait a support on this matter from `django-model-utils` themselves?

Comment: This may surely happen at some point, but I doubt it'll happen any soon. Django is a very bad candidate for typing, and this will be not widely useful (and, of course, this is about maintainer's time - I suppose there are many more interesting things to do). You may rise an issue on their tracker to ask the maintainer directly, but I think you have a better chance to DIY quickly instead of asking somebody else to do it in their free time.